# Trouble running Android apps on phone from Eclipse Mac, "adb devices" lists device correctly

Tags: java, android, eclipse, macos, adb

I'm using Eclipse on my Mac running 10.8.5 and trying to setup my Android dev environment.  The problem I'm having is I can't seem to run apps from Eclipse to my HTC One (Dev Edition).  I have USB Debugging enabled and the device even lists when I run "ADB Devices" from terminal.   It also shows up under DDMS in Eclipse.  I've tried the two USB ports I have and it doesn't work still.  Any ideas?

Comment: How are you trying to install it? Did you check the console output to see if you're getting any errors?

Comment: One possibility is the "secure USB debugging feature" which is basically an opt-in dialog that pops up on your phone to confirm that your Mac is allowed to have debugging access. If you set up your phone with multiple accounts you must switch to the primary account to see that dialog. Is the device listed correctly with a serial number / device name or is it just a bunch of question marks?

Comment: No errors in the console, I've accepted the secure USB debugging feature and it does indeed list the correct serial number in my terminal prompt.  I actually just downloaded the Android Studio preview from Google and it was able to connect to my HTC One and push the test app to it.  Weird.

Comment: did U added any minsdk as 18 in your manifest.xml?

Comment: I have minSdkVersion set to 8 and targetSdkVersion set to 17.  So that should be good.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, i solved it by installing htc sync which for some reason seem to make it work. http://www.htc.com/us/support/software/htc-sync-manager.aspx - think that's where i got it from